# UITableViewCell incorrect X positions

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been searching through here and googling like crazy for a possible solution to this problem. Thus far I'm turning up exactly nothing that actually fixes it so I'm hoping someone can help.

I'm working on the UI for a iPad app. I'm doing it using interface builder. I worked with storyboards briefly but I don't like them all that much so I'm sticking with IB for now. Unfortunately I'm not very experienced with the workings of IOS Ui but it's been going relatively smoothly so far. In my app, I have a view controller, which holds a view containing a pair of sub views. One subview contains a rather windows like header bar (i like the look). The second contains a UITableView. The UITableView is set up properly as far as I can tell, and feeds it's info from a data source using custom UITableViewCells. The UITableView is set to grouped though currently there is only one section. The table is in edit mode by default because I want the user to be able to add new items and use the VC as a selection dialog. The view controller is presented (rather than pushed) using UIModalPresentationFormSheet (again, because I like the view) but I don't know that has any bearing on the problem. The cell border is flush with the X origin, the only reason the text isn't currently starting there is because I went into my cell and move the label over, leaving a gap between the edge of the cell and the label containing my text.

[The Offending View http://bit.ly/144cbjT](http://bit.ly/144cbjT)

The Problem: The UITableViewCells, for some reason are positioning themselves at X: 0. This puts them outside the border drawn on the UITablewView when you set it to grouped style. I could probably just turn off the border and get away with it, but I like the look so i want to keep it. I've tried messing around with constraints and anchor points on the cells, the content of the cells, the table itself, the view... I've tried simply moving my cell's labels over a bit. I've also had clipping subviews turned on and off. I've made sure the controls are being loaded properly from the XIB. I've made sure everything is added as a subview where needed. I've made sure I've tried everything I could think of short of setting the cell's X position in code. But since I'm not sure how to tell where the border is, I'd rather have the tableview or the cell do the work itself.

The question: How do I fix this? The selection accessory should be outside the grouping box. The text should be inside, not bleeding out onto the background like it is.I believe the content of the cell should be displayed inside the border within the yellow area.

The odd thing is, this is my fifth or sixth table in this app and I've been doing them all basically the same. Thus far this is the only one I've had trouble with.

Can anyone shed some light as to what's going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put the link to your screenshot to the question, somebody will take care of editing for you.

Comment: Ok well the screenie is here: http://bit.ly/144cbjT

Comment: I'm still googling... and I'm noticing pretty much every custom UITableViewCell tutorial includes an image on the left hand side of the cell. The apple doc for UITableViewCell (here: http://bit.ly/144e5Rn) also mentions that an 'accessory' and an image is part of every cell.

It doesn't say it anywhere, but i wonder if you have to account for that image? I would have thought that if it was required it would have been part of the underlying class.

As an experiment I've moved my main label to the right about 25 px or so and it lines up just fine. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you don't set the image, it doesn't take up any space.  I don't use it very often, so I'm not sure if it is a fixed size when set, or it depends on the image size.  Should be pretty obvious if you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that to get this in code, you'd have to do something explicit, so the most likely candidate is a messed up IB file.

Since it doesn't cost anything, I'd just delete the tableView from the IB and then re-add it.  If that doesn't work, try recreating the complete IB.

Hope that helps

Comment: Does that happen a lot? I've had to trash a couple of IB files so far because i couldn't figure out what the heck was wrong with them.

Comment: @E K It's just easier to make unwanted changes at IB as it automates a lot for you, if you change everything carefully and with understanding of the results all your xibs will be fine.

Comment: I still don't know what happened... but I deleted the Xib and recreated it..and now it's lined up properly. I hate voodoo stuff like this. But at least it worked.

thank you.

Comment: Happens occasionally to me, but these are the symptoms: Some wierdness happening that you can't account for.  I spent a day messing with layout constraints because of a messed up IB.
If you seriously want to know what the problem was, you can look at the IB, it is an XML file, and although it is pretty dense, you should be able to find differences.